# What is the problem in the last line of the code "Selection.FillDown"?

Tags: excel, vba

This is Excel VBA code.

```vb
Sub Sales_Macro()
'
' Sales_Macro Macro
'
'
    Rows("1:10").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        
    Range("E:E,H:H,K:K,N:N").Select
    Range("N1").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
        
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
        
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$298").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
            "Accountant: ANNE", "Accountant: ANTHONY", "Accountant: BRADD", _
            "Accountant: BRIAND", "Accountant: BRIANP", "Accountant: CODY", _
            "Accountant: CYRUS", "Accountant: DAN", "Accountant: DEBBIE", "Accountant: DONNA", _
            "Accountant: EKATERINA", "Accountant: JEFF", "Accountant: JENN", _
            "Accountant: JEREMY", "Accountant: JOSEPH", "Accountant: SHEEJA123"), Operator _
            :=xlFilterValues
        
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        
    Range("K1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]"
        
    Range("K1").Select
    Selection.FillDown
```

I do know that the last line would require a range so that error '1004' does not occur. But the problem is that when I recorded the macro to get the code, there was no range defined. And the filldown cells are not linear. The cells go like K1, K22, K24, etc. (because I am using a filter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you intend your FillDown to only affect the visible rows after your AutoFilter is applied.  You cannot simply apply a FillDown to a set of non-contiguous rows such as are visible after AutoFilter is applied.  You must *iterate* through each rectangular sub-area.

First, at the top of your SubRoutine add the following statement to declare two variables, FilterRng and SubRng:

```
Dim FilterRng as Range, SubRng as Range
```

Then instead of your last four lines of code, do this to find the visible range and iterate through the areas:

```
 Set FilterRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)  'Set a range of visible rows

 For Each SubRng In FilterRng.Areas    'Go through each set of contiguous rows
    SubRng(1, 11).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]"
    If SubRng.Rows.Count > 1 Then SubRng.FillDown
 Next SubRng
```